# Como reabrir um pull request fechado no GitHub?

Tags: github

Eu recebi hoje um Pull Request de uma pessoa no meu repositório do GitHub, porém acabei fechando sem querer através da aba de comentário. Como faço para reabrir e aceitar o Pull Request fechado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá até o final da página do Pull Request, logo abaixo da caixa de texto, tem o botão `Reopen pull request`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]